# How to get the Id of current row using knockout Js for hiding the remove button

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there any way to hide the delete button/div only for first row in knockout js. i have nested templates. and if use `$index` it hides the remove button but also does the same for nested templates as they will have again the same index.

I had tried many thing but nothing works. I only want to hide the content of **logical-div** only if is the first row. and this template is repeating with same attributes/values. below is the HTML part.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemtemplate', foreach: $root.subitemsOf(null) }"></ul>

        <script type="text/html" id="itemtemplate">
            <li>                

                    <div class="logical-div" style="margin-top: 5px; width:250px; border:1px solid gray;display:inline-block">                      
                        <select class='logical-inner-div' data-bind="options: $root.Condition, selectedOptions:logicalConditionSelected , optionsValue: 'logicalConditionVal', optionsText: 'logicalConditionName'" style="width:200px;">
                        </select>                       
                    </div>

                <table class="block" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select  data-bind="options: $root.tag, selectedOptions:tagSelected , optionsValue: 'tagVal', optionsText: 'tagName'" style="width:80px;">
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select  data-bind="options: $root.isNot,selectedOptions:isNotSelected , optionsValue: 'isNotVal', optionsText: 'isNotName'" style="width:80px;">
                            </select> 
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <select  data-bind="options: $root.alias,selectedOptions:aliasSelected, optionsValue: 'aliasVal', optionsText: 'aliasName'" style="width:300px;">

                            </select> 
                        </td>

                        <td>

                                <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeSegment"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/images/removeitem.gif';?>" alt="Delete"></a>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="add-condition btn btn-primary btn-small" data-bind="click: $root.addNestedSegment" >Add Nested Block</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                <ul data-bind="template: {name: 'itemtemplate', foreach: $root.subitemsOf($data)}"></ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                
            </li>
        </script>
```

Some of JS Part.

```
function ItemModel(id, parent_id, initialLogicalVal,initialTagVal,initialIsNotVal,initialAliasVal) {
        var self = this;

        self.id = ko.observable(id);
        self.parentId = ko.observable(parent_id);    
        self.logicalConditionSelected = ko.observable([initialLogicalVal]);
        self.tagSelected = ko.observable([initialTagVal]);
        self.isNotSelected = ko.observable([initialIsNotVal]);
        self.aliasSelected = ko.observable([initialAliasVal]);


    }

    var viewModel = function RecursiveListViewModel(tasks) 
    {
        var self = this;

 // Knock out function for checking the parents
        self.subitemsOf = function (item) {
            var children = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function (arrayItem) {
                var parentItemId = (null === item) ? null : item.id();
                return arrayItem.parentId() == parentItemId;
            });
            return children;
        };
        // Knock out function for checking if there are child for this record for populating nested records
        self.hasSubitems = function (item) {
            var firstMatch = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.items(), function (arrayItem) {
                return (arrayItem.parentId() == item.id());
            });

            return (null !== firstMatch); // At least one item found in array
        };
// Knock out function for Adding the nested/child segment
        self.addNestedSegment = function(item) {

            self.items.push(new ItemModel(++ChildId, item.id(),'and','Tag','Is Not',firstAlias));
        }

        // Knock out function for Adding the Main/Parent segment
        self.addMainSegment = function(data, event) {
            self.items.push(new ItemModel(++ChildId, null,'and','Tag','Is Not',firstAlias));
        }

        // Knock out function for Deleting the segment with all of its children
        self.removeSegment = function(data,item) 
        { 
            self.items.remove(data);
        } 
}
```

Comment: put some code, It is difficult to understand your point

Comment: You can use `:first` pseudo.

Comment: Where is the "nested templates" aspect of this?  Could you trim this down to just be the relevant parts?  Some minimal version that demonstrates the problem (With stuff like styling cut out, for one)

Comment: Can you please post the model? What does addNestedSegment do? Is it interacting with the DOM?

Comment: addNestedSegment add the same object but a child of row, where it has been called.

Comment: create a small sample of the above code in jsfiddle. It will make it easier to suggest solutions.

Comment: Can u post the html output of the current solution , so that we get better idea abt what to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the $index variable, you can check the object reference:

```
<!-- ko if: $data != $root.items()[0] -->
<div class="logical-div">
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Or using some observable, like

```
<!-- ko if: $data != firstItem() -->
<div class="logical-div">
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

self.firstItem = ko.computed(function() { return self.items()[0]; });
```

The != operator in the sentence check if both objects are the same (if they point to the same object in memory). Because the first rendered element is the same as self.items()[0] then knockout will hide this div element (in this case, the ko if does not hide the element; it does not render it)

Greetings!